# .change() seems to be lagging behind by one turn

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/691t4709/3/ it seems to update the value no problem, but the value is only updated (and therefore the correct APR is only applied) when you change it once more, so for example if you select 5 years and then 2 years the 2 years would show 4.9% not 0%.

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#months').change(function(){
      $('#interest_rate option').prop('disabled', false);
        if(this.value == '24')
          $('#interest_rate option:not([value="0"])')
          .prop('disabled', true).parent().val('0');
        else if(this.value == '60')
          $('#interest_rate option:not([value="4.9"])')
          .prop('disabled', true).parent().val('4.9');
        else if(this.value == '120')
          $('#interest_rate option:not([value="5.9"])')
          .prop('disabled', true).parent().val('5.9');
    });
  });
```

Comment: Which browser and version are you using?

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me, tested on Google Chrome.

Comment: Your fiddle works just fine for me. On changing selected time span the given percent value is changing instantly. Switched to 5 year -> 4.9% ... switch back to 2 years -> 0% ... using Firefox

Comment: it works fine here too (firefox last version). Is there some other code near it in your project that could interact with this and cause problems?

Comment: Sorry I mean the 'total cost of credit' doesn't update fluently, the dropdown portion seems to work perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated code. Instead of `if-else`, you can move that to `switch-case` and call `computeLoan()` after the `change` is complete (i.e at the end of it)

```js
function computeLoan() {
  var amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;
  var interest_rate = document.getElementById('interest_rate').value;
  var months = document.getElementById('months').value;
  var interest = (amount * (interest_rate * .01)) / months;
  var payment = ((amount / months) + interest).toFixed(2);

  var payment_total = (payment * months).toFixed(2);
  var interest_total = (interest * months).toFixed(2);

  payment = payment.toString().replace(/B(?=(d{3})+(?!d))/g, ",");
  payment_total = payment_total.toString().replace(/B(?=(d{3})+(?!d))/g, ",");
  interest_total = interest_total.toString().replace(/B(?=(d{3})+(?!d))/g, ",");

  document.getElementById('monthly-payments').innerHTML = document.getElementById('months').value + " monthly <br> payments of";
  document.getElementById('payment').innerHTML = "£" + payment;
  document.getElementById('total-repayment').innerHTML = "£" + payment_total;
  document.getElementById('total-cost-credit').innerHTML = "£" + interest_total;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#months').change(function() {
    $('#interest_rate option').prop('disabled', false);
    switch (this.value) {
      case '24':
        $('#interest_rate option:not([value="0"])')
          .prop('disabled', true).parent().val('0');
        break;
      case '60':
        $('#interest_rate option:not([value="4.9"])')
          .prop('disabled', true).parent().val('4.9');
        break;
      case '120':
        $('#interest_rate option:not([value="5.9"])')
          .prop('disabled', true).parent().val('5.9');
        break;
    }
    computeLoan();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_2_3">
    <label style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Amount to borrow:</label>
    <input type="range" name="loan_input" id="amount" value="1000" min="1000" max="30000" step="250" oninput="amount_output.value = amount.value" onchange="computeLoan()" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
  </div>
  <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_3" style="margin-right: 0;">
    <label style="opacity: 0; margin-bottom: 10px;">Amount to borrow:</label>
    <p></p>
    <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
      <div class="input-group-addon">£</div>
      <output class="form-control currency" name="amount_output" id="amount_output">1000</output>
      <div class="input-group-addon">.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <label style="margin-bottom: 10px;">To pay back over:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="months" onchange="computeLoan()" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
      <option value="24">2 Years</option>
      <option value="60">5 Years</option>
      <option value="120">10 Years</option>
   </select>
  <label>The interest rate is determined by the length of the loan:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="interest_rate" onchange="computeLoan()">
      <option value="0">0% (2 Years)</option>
      <option value="4.9">4.9% (5 Years)</option>
      <option value="5.9">5.9% (10 Years)</option>
   </select>
</form>

<p style="border-bottom: 1px dashed #e5e5e5; padding-bottom: 10px;">Total Repayment: <span id="total-repayment" class="pull-right">£1,000.08</span></p>
<p style="border-bottom: 1px dashed #e5e5e5; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-bottom: 20px;">Total Cost of Credit: <span id="total-cost-credit" class="pull-right">£0.00</span></p>
<p id="monthly-payments">
</p>
<p id="payment">
</p>
</p>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output element appears to be missing. There is no element with id 'monthly-payments'

The real problem however is that you have no control over the order in which the events are firing off. Your computeLoan function is bound by the onchange attribute on your element, whilst you have another anonymous function manipulating the values for this attached via jQuery.

A bit of research shows that jquery will call events in the order that they were added. As the onclick event is added first, it will compute the loan and then update the values in the controls (which is why you are seeing the lag).

The simplest solution is to call computeLoan at the end of your anonymous function to make sure it uses the latest value of the elements.

Other solutions solutions include binding computeLoan with jquery after your anonymous function or just combining the functions!

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#months').change(function(){
      $('#interest_rate option').prop('disabled', false);
      console.log(this.value);
        if(this.value == '24')
          $('#interest_rate option:not([value="0"])')
          .prop('disabled', true).parent().val('0');
        else if(this.value == '60')
          $('#interest_rate option:not([value="4.9"])')
          .prop('disabled', true).parent().val('4.9');
        else if(this.value == '120')
          $('#interest_rate option:not([value="5.9"])')
          .prop('disabled', true).parent().val('5.9');
          computeLoan();
    });
  });
```

[Edited code here](https://jsfiddle.net/691t4709/4/)

Comment: I didn't copy that part because that seems to be working, it's just the total cost of credit which doesn't update